Can we make $u_i = [x_i]$ for $\{ u_1, \dots, u_m \} \subseteq k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ through suitable change of coordinates in $k^n$?
Let $k$ be a ( possibly algebraically closed ) field. Let $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be polynomial ring with $I \subseteq k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ an ideal. Let $u_1 , \dots, u_m $ ( $m \le n$ ) be elements of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ algebraically independent over $k$ such that each $u_i$ is $k$-linear combination of $[x_i]$ 's. Then my question is, by a suitable change of coordinates in $k^n$, can we make $u_i = [x_i]$ for $i=1,\dots, m$?

First, as stated in question, let $u_ i = a_{i,1}[x_1] + \cdots + a_{i,n}[x_n]$ ( $ 1 \le i \le m $ ) be $k$-linear combinations. Then since $u_1, \dots, u_m$ are algebraically independent over $k$ ( so that linearly independent over $k$ ), $\{ ( a_{1,1}, \dots, a_{1,n}) , ( a_{2,1} , \dots, a_{2,n}), \dots , (a_{m,1} , \dots, a_{m,n} ) \}$ is linearly independent. So we can extend this set to the basis of $k^{n}$ and we obtain invertible $n \times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ with $(a_{i,1}, \dots, a_{i,n} )$ as its $i$ 'th row ( $1\le i \le m$ ).
Second, consider a map $\Phi : k[X_1, \dots, X_n] \to k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, $X_i \mapsto a_{i,1}x_1 + \cdots + a_{i,n} x_n$. Then $\Phi$ is $k$-ring isomorphism ( True? ). Note that $[\Phi(X_i) ] = u_i $ ( $ 1\le  i \le m$ ) in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n ]/I$. After renaming $X_1, \dots, X_n$ as $x_1, \dots, x_n$, then upto the isomorphism, we get $u_i = [x_i]$.

We begin by interpreting the quotient ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ as the ring of polynomial functions on the affine variety in $k^n$ cut out by $I$. In that geometric picture, each class $[x_i]$ is the restriction of the coordinate function $x_i$ to that variety, and each $u_j$ is a linear polynomial in the same restricted sense, namely a $k$-linear combination of the $[x_i]$.
To establish that we can rechoose coordinates so that $[x_i]$ become exactly the given $u_i$ for $i=1,...,m$, we must first verify that $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ are linearly independent specifically in the vector space of linear forms of the quotient ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$. If there exists a nontrivial linear combination $\lambda_1u_1+...+\lambda_mu_m = 0$ in the quotient (equivalently, $\lambda_1u_1+...+\lambda_mu_m \in I$), then these forms cannot serve as independent coordinate functions.
Assuming $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ is indeed a linearly independent family in the space of linear forms of the quotient, we can extend it to a maximal linearly independent set $\{u_1,...,u_m,v_{m+1},...,v_r\}$ in that same space, where $r \leq n$. When $r < n$, this indicates that the linear functions in the quotient ring do not span all coordinate directions - geometrically, this suggests the affine variety might be embedded in a lower-dimensional subspace of $k^n$.
Each $u_j$ is a linear form in the quotient:
$$
u_j = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk}[x_k]
$$
where these coefficients $a_{jk}$ form an $m \times n$ matrix $A$. The $j$-th row $(a_{j1},...,a_{jn})$ encodes the coefficients of $u_j$ in front of the $[x_k]$. Linear independence of $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ ensures we can extract an invertible $m \times m$ submatrix. Let $B=(b_{ij})$ be its inverse, so $B \cdot A = I_{m \times m}$.
Note that we can extend this $m \times m$ invertible submatrix to a full $n \times n$ invertible matrix $M \in GL_n(k)$ by:

Taking a complement to the row span of the original matrix
Forming a basis including the invertible submatrix
Arranging in block form if desired

Now consider the sum:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}u_j = \sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk}[x_k]\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}a_{jk}\right)[x_k]
$$
Since $B \cdot A = I$, we have $\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}a_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$ (the Kronecker delta). Therefore:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{ik}[x_k] = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}[x_k] = u_i
$$
For the formal change of coordinates, we define an automorphism:
$$
\Phi: k[x_1,...,x_n] \longrightarrow k[x_1,...,x_n]
$$
arising from our invertible linear map:
$$
(x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto (y_1,...,y_n) = M(x_1,...,x_n)^T
$$
where $M \in \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ is our extended matrix. Here $\Phi$ is the substitution homomorphism sending each $y_i$ to its corresponding linear polynomial in $x_1,...,x_n$.
For $\Phi$ to descend to a well-defined map on the quotient:
$$
\Phi: k[x_1,...,x_n] \twoheadrightarrow k[x_1,...,x_n]/I
$$
we need $y_i - \sum_k a_{ik}x_k \in I$ for $i=1,...,m$. This is ensured by our construction since $M$ was built precisely to implement these relations.
Geometrically:

$\Phi$ represents a relabelling of coordinates in $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$
While the variety $V(I)$ may move as a subset of $k^n$, it remains isomorphic
The new coordinate functions $[y_i]$ coincide with our chosen linear forms $u_i$
The fact that $\Phi$ is an automorphism ensures the quotient map is well-defined

Thus the necessary and sufficient condition for finding coordinates $[y_1],...,[y_m]$ matching $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ is that $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ be linearly independent in the quotient. When this holds, our construction shows how to embed them into a linear basis of the degree-one piece of the quotient and use the inverse of that embedding to define the required coordinate change.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Uhm..Thank you. And, You wrote in the fourth paragraph ; "We similarly extend to a complete ~~. This yields a global  change of coordinates $(y_1, \dots, y_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots , x_n)$ in which, modulo $I$, the new coordinates $[y_1] , \dots, [y_m]$ coincide with ${u_1, \dots, u_m }$. " What are the domain and codomain of the correspondence $(y_1, \dots, , y_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ ? Can you explain your sentence more friendly, formally?

Your overall discussion is a bit difficult to understand.

@Plantation: see updated answer

O.K.  Q.1.) Why $\sum_{j=1}^{m} b_{ij}u_j = u_i $? Can you explain this more friendly? Q.2.) In the 5th paragraph, can you exhibit the automorphism of $k[x_1 , \dots, x_n]$ more formally? And can you explain the correspondence of $[y_i]$ to $u_i$ via passing to the quotient by $I$?

Please understand my speed of understanding.

Uhm.. For the Q.2.), I guess that isomorphism $k[y_1, \dots, y_n] \cong k[x_1 , \dots, x_n]$ is more proper for what you meant , rather than automorphim of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. How do you think about that?

In the 5th paragraph, why $
\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{ik}[x_k] = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}[x_k]$ ?
